# What does the Principal Principle say about our rational credences in outcomes?

Tags: belief

According to David Lewis, the Principal Principle says that “our beliefs about the objective chances of outcomes (typically) determine our rational credences in those outcomes.”

I’m assuming that this means that on the next roll of a dice, one should have a 1/6 credence in the dice landing on a 1. However, if one has a 1/6 credence for each outcome, then it follows that one should have a 0% credence in any other outcome (such as the dice spontaneously turning into a fly).

However, Bayesians who often invoke Cromwell’s rule refuse to assign a zero or 1 prior to anything. Given this, is one supposed to then assign a credence slightly below 1/6 to each outcome of the dice? If so, wouldn’t that then contradict the Principal Principle?

Comment: In practice, it is physically possible for a die to land on an edge or a corner. Or perhaps not to land at all: maybe a magpie flies in and grabs it and it's never seen again. So, the appropriate degrees of credence for the six faces are very slightly less than 1/6.

Comment: @Bumble Similar, I have tossed a coin before and it land on its side. Only once in my life has it happened, but these things can occur.

Comment: The Principal Principle is problematic because it assumes that objective chances exist when they do not. Objective chances would imply that single case chances exist. But these suffer from the reference class problem.

Comment: Under principal principle a correct physical chance theory up to time t has to mirror degree of credence probability up to same time t without inadmissible evidence, therefore every possibility could be grasped in thought completely in principle via its physical mirror and since the said objective chance theory is correct thus modal realism is tautological as supported by probabilism, the totality is nothing but the totality of total possibilities, nothing is actually actualized or decided...

Answer (score 0):

The Principal Principle is problematic because it assumes that objective chances exist when they do not. Objective chances would imply that single case chances exist. A single case chance is the probability of an event that has no dependence on previous trials or events that are “similar” to it.

For example, suppose I am about to toss a dice and I want to figure out what my credence should be for it to land on 1/6. It has an objective chance of 1/6 and so it should obviously be 1/6 or close to it, correct?

Well, this might make sense as an idealized trial but reality never works like that. Suppose you find out that the dice was manufactured from an untrustworthy company. How do you then change your credence? Surely, there is a nonzero probability that the dice is biased. In order to say that the objective chance of a dice landing on 1 is 1/6, you have to know in advance that it is fair but you can never actually know this. You can only assume it.

When you change the example, this credence function becomes even more problematic. What is the probability that John will have cancer in the next year? Well John belongs to many different groups: men, the group of people who are 52, the group of people who live in Wisconsin if he lives in Wisconsin, etc. But with respect to each class, there is a different probability. But which probability do you then choose for your credence? What if you decide to put John in his own new class? Given that there are no previous instances of that class, you can’t even calculate a conditional probability!

So in summary, credences can only map to objective chances if those chances exist. But it is clear that they do not.

Comment: Many people interpret quantum mechanical events as indeterministic. The probability of an atom of carbon-14 undergoing radioactive decay some time in the next 5730 years is 0.5, so by the principal principle the appropriate degree of credence that this will happen is also 0.5. Outside of quantum mechanics I'm inclined to agree that probabilities are better understood as rational degrees of credence rather than some kind of objective chance. This does not make it impossible to speak of the probability of unique events, because we can have stochastic models.

Comment: Fair point. Yes, I agree that objective chances may exist in the case of QM (although I’m not well versed in it, so can’t really make that conclusion). Overall, I think if objective chances for an event don’t exist (an event after all is just an abstraction), then no rational credence can exist. One can marshall arguments to show for example why betting on a dice landing on 1 is less preferable to betting on a coin landing on heads. However, this is philosophy, not math. It is no different from an argument that says we should bet on the sun rising tomorrow vs. not.

Comment: Or to put it another way, “betting on a coin landing on heads vs. dice landing on 1” isn’t any more objective of a decision than “betting on the sun rising tomorrow vs. not” or even “betting on god existing”. Many philosophers have proposed that the first kind of bet somehow has an objective answer compared to the latter two but this would be inaccurate. Probability is just one of many concepts and models that people can use to try to make decisions with and nothing more.

Comment: Degrees of credence exist, and there is plenty of theory supporting the idea that we can use probabilities to quantify them, at least to a good approximation. How 'objective' this is would be a matter of debate. One cannot just use math to compel people to agree about things. But some combinations of credences are definitely more rational than others.

Comment: Wait what? How would you “show” that degrees of credence exist? All we know is that we make bets when picking A over B. There is no evidence that we operate based on degrees psychologically. Even if we did, there is no ontological basis for them as mentioned earlier. “But some combinations of credences are definitely more rational than others.” You cannot show this without question begging. What is the most rational credence for belief in a flat earth? Give me a range and why. It is better to simply say that a proposition like that has no evidence and to just dismiss it as a whole.

Comment: One of the most common approaches to cognitive psychology involves understanding degrees of belief as probabilities, and belief revision as Bayesian updating, so there is an abundance of evidence that we operate with degrees of credence. Decision theory is also largely based on assigning degrees of credence to possible outcomes and treating them as probabilities. Probability theory itself can be derived from considerations of rational decision making or from considerations of how probable inferences can be made.